# Elegant ways to express coordinates and zoom level in urls

Tags: coordinates, web-mapping, url

To make sharing map locations more natural I'm looking at updating a map service to sync the browser url with the current center point coordinate and zoom level the user is viewing.

At present the service is using uglier url parameters e.g.

```
map?lat=-43.273331&lon=171.960411&zoom=12
```

What other friendly formats are in use out there already or could you suggest?

Some methods I've seen in the wild include:

- http://maps.gsi.go.jp/#16/40.649778/140.268438
- https://www.google.com/maps/place/Amsterdam,+Netherlands/@52.3545362,4.7638767,11z/

I realize some of you will suggest using a bounding box instead of a single center point, but in this case different topo imagery is shown at different zoom levels so I'd like to preserve the level of detail the current user is looking at when shared. Topo250's and topo50's in this case.

I feel the url parameter approach is uglier as they are longer and potentially mixed in with other page url parameters.

Comment: IMO, the zoom parameter in the first version is more clear than the other two. Does the `#` symbol refer to the zoom level? That's not as clear as the original `zoom=` option. And one could mis-read the `11z` format  in your final option as though the `z` parameter is a Z coordinate.

Comment: Actually I really appreciate when an URL explicitly says which coordinate is latitude and which is longitude. Often in GIS they get reversed, so you never know if you're looking at lat/long or long/lat.

Comment: What makes them ugly?

Comment: I can see a number of votes to delete this question. I imagine as it seems a bit more web development? But I feel the best people that might have experience and views on this are GIS professionals.